# What's causing this freaky time travel with make?

Tags: makefile

I have a file, tmp containing:

```
{
    "VolumeId": "vol--22222222", 
}
```

and a makefile, containing only:

```
MYFILE =latest

x:  
    \cp tmp $(MYFILE)
    grep VolumeId $(MYFILE)
    @echo $(shell grep VolumeId $(MYFILE))
```

If I run make x, I get:

```
\cp tmp latest
grep VolumeId latest
    "VolumeId": "vol--22222222", 
VolumeId: vol--22222222,
```

as expected. If I modify the file tmp, replacing 2's wit 4's, I get:

```
\cp tmp latest
grep VolumeId latest
    "VolumeId": "vol--44444444444", 
VolumeId: vol--22222222,
```

...huh? The greps return different results! The second contains data from the file *before* the copy.

I run

```
rm latest ; make x
```

I get:

```
\cp tmp latest
grep VolumeId latest
    "VolumeId": "vol--4444444444",
```

What's going on here?

GNU Make 3.81. Ubuntu 12.04 on VMWare 5.

---

**Update 1**

Here's a more explicit example

```
CMD0 =$(shell date +"%s.%N")
CMD1 =date +"%s.%N"
CMD2 =date +"%s.%N"
y:
    @sleep 2
    @date +"%s.%N"    # 2nd 
    @echo $(CMD0)     # 1st A
    @sleep 2
    @date +"%s.%N"    # 3rd
    @sleep 2
    @$(CMD1)          # 4th
    @sleep 2
    @echo $(shell $(CMD2) )   # 1st B
```

Output:

```
1381596581.761093768
1381596579.743610973
1381596583.769058027
1381596585.774766561
1381596579.751625601
```

Its look like all the $(shell ... ) commands get evaluated together before any line of the y recipe.

This is a little surprising (and counter-intuitive - what's the rationale for this odd design?). It has important consequences if the shell commands have side effects. Also, I can't find any documentation in make manual that describes this order of evaluation.

---

**Update 2**

What's especially odd about the above is that its hard to come up with a mental model for the order of evaluation. Is it that any rule of the form, $(function ... ) is executed before each line of the recipe? If so, why is $(CMD0) evaluated before the recipe, but not $(CMD1). Its true that CMD0 *contains* a $(f ... ) - does make look at this, even though CMD0 is declared as a delayed evaluated variable (i.e.declared with = not :=)?

---

**Update 3**

Reducing it down to essential components:

```
notSafe:
    backup-everything                        # Format executed even if backup fails
    echo $(shell format-disk) | tee log.txt  # 

CMDX =$(shell format-disk)
alsoNotSafe:
    backup-everything           # Format executed even if backup fails
    echo $(CMDX) | tee log.txt  # Even though CMDX is a delayed evaluation variable


CMDZ =format-disk
safe:
    backup-everything        # Works as expected. 
    $(CMDZ) | tee log.txt    # Evaluation of CMDZ is delayed until line is executed.
```

Mad. Who designed this?

Comment: Looks like the shell expansion is done before executing your commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not telling us everything: when you run it the 1st time, you echo an empty line.  Instead you get a grep file not found error.

And that's the decisive hint: `$`-expressions are evaluated by any variant of make **before** running the commands of the rule.  I.e. in each later run you see the file contents of the previous run.

Btw. your leading backslash is spurious and causes the command to be passed to the Shell, instead of being directly executed by make.  With [makepp's](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) builtin commands (prefixed by `&`) and fixed dependencies that would be:

```
latest: tmp
    &cp $(input) $(output)
    &grep VolumeId $(output)
    @&echo $(&grep VolumeId $(output))
```

That doesn't change the problem, but by using the proper rule variables, makes it obvious what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks. When you say expression. Do you mean anything starting with $, or anything with the form $(function ... )

Comment: GNU make variables are expanded, and functions executed, prior to running recipes. Recipes are executed running the shell specified in `$(SHELL)`, so having `$(shell ...)` in your recipe means you first execute the shell to help determine what command is going to be fed to the shell when the recipe is executed. You can look this stuff up in the GNU make manual, make sure you use the manual for the GNU make version you're using.

Comment: BTW what are the `&`s supposed to be doing in front of your commands?

Comment: The answer is in the sentence just before the code snippet:  It is the syntax chosen by [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) to call a builtin command.  No Shell command starts with `&`, nor does any make function, hence a good extension prefix.

Comment: @user48956: There are three ways of writing make-expressions: `$(xyz)` or equivalently `${xyz}` are the normal way of expanding variables or functions.  If you have a single character variable name, including all the cryptic symbols, you can omit the parentheses: `$x`, `$^`, `$1` or `$$` (the last one is constant and evaluates to `$`.